# Order of execution in WHERE clause not allowing CAST of varchar AS date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below:

Name: VW_Questionnaire

| QuestionnaireId (int) (pk) | QuestionId (int) | Question (varchar) | Response (varchar) | Tag (varchar) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | How many classes do you have? | 4 | null |
| 2 | 2 | When is your first day of class? | 2022-09-01 | SP1 |
| 3 | 1 | How many classes do you have? | 9 | null |
| 4 | 2 | When is your first day of class? | 2022-10-01 | SP1 |

The below code works:

```
SELECT Question, Response
From VW_Questionnaire
WHERE QuestionId = 2
      AND CAST(Response AS Date) < SELECT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

The below code throws an error:

```
SELECT Question, Response
From VW_Questionnaire
WHERE Tag = 'SP1'
      AND CAST(Response AS Date) < SELECT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

It seems like in the first example, it first filters to WHERE QuestionId = 2 and then it successfully can CAST Response AS Date.

However, in the second example, it seems like it's attempting to CAST Response AS Date before it filters to WHERE Tag = 'SP1'.

I even tried to do this with a CTE where within the CTE I do the filter to WHERE Tag = 'SP1' and then I SELECT from this filtered table and CAST Response AS date.  I'm still met with the conversion error.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You know you can just use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` rather than `SELECT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` right?

Comment: You have little or no control over the order in which the database engine evaluates the data, nor do you know how many rows it attempts to filter against because you don't know which part of the where clause gets executed first. Therefore if you have invalid data in your database it can cause issues such as this even when you are trying to filter that data out. A good reason to store your data correctly in the correct datatype rather than mixing them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is a declarative language. This means that the server is free to reorder your predicates as it sees fit, in order to hit indexes and improve performance.

Therefore, you cannot rely on the predicates being executed in left-to-right order. Instead, you can just use `TRY_CAST`, which will null out any invalid values

```sql
SELECT Question, Response
FROM VW_Questionnaire
WHERE QuestionId = 2
  AND TRY_CAST(Response AS Date) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Note that the point about reordering even applies in derived tables and views. For example, you may still get an error in this version:

```sql
SELECT Question, Response
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM VW_Questionnaire
    WHERE QuestionId = 2
) v
WHERE CAST(Response AS Date) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

The only construct guaranteed to evaluate from left-to-right is `CASE` (and even that guarantee only applies to scalar values, not aggregates).

---

I strongly recommend you ensure your data is in the correct format in the first place, so you don't need to cast it.

Comment: TRY_CAST is a working option.

Response is a generic field that gathers data based on numerous questions which have responses can be formatted from text responses, dates, booleans, integers, etc.

The responses will always be formatted appropriately for the question type, but the all fall into the same Response field.

Maybe there was a better design for this Response table, but for now, TRY_CAST allows the filter to perform as needed.

Comment: @CGSD yeah a *better* (IMHO) design for a answer table is a column for each answer type you might expect e.g. string, number, bool, datetime. That gives you much better control over queries etc.

Comment: @CGSD That is what I would recommend also (along with a `CHECK` constraint to ensure only one possible field is not null at a time). At a pinch you could also do this with a `sql_variant` column, but you would still need `TRY_CAST` then.

Comment: @DaleK I agree with you, but was unsure how to set something up like this.  I basically have a question table and a response table which are then tied together into a view.   The questions are repeated and answered multiple times by different users.  


I created a view that can tie the response table to the question table and not have to repeat the questions every time and just refer to the QuestionId.


Maybe the solution would be to create numerous response tables for each response data type and then union all of the results together into a view?

Comment: I wouldn't use separate table, use separate columns. And then store as part of the question the answer type you are expecting (string, number etc) and then if you need to view the results as one column use a case expression to determine which column to display.

Comment: @DaleK the issue becomes when a user inputs a response on the front end, redirecting that answer to a different field depending on the question rather than a singular response field

Comment: Thats all fairly easy logic to deal with

Comment: For everyone saying "the schema should be this way", I worked at an online survey company for seven years and specifically in a data heavy role. While what you're proposing is academically correct (and maybe the way it would be done in a greenfield scenario!), it has other implications. As is often the case, the real world doesn't always agree with what is the One True Way™.